# How to handle pagination with Pundit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pundit

I've just started using the Pundit gem for authorisation in a Rails 4 app.

Everything's going fine but I can get my head around how pagination will work in the index action.

My controller's index action looks like:

```
def index
   @records = policy_scope(Record)
end
```

The Scope class within my RecordPolicy then goes:

```
 class Scope < Struct.new(:user, :scope)
    def resolve
      if user.has_role? :admin
        # get all records
      else
        # get user specific records
      end
    end
  end
```

This all works fine. I'd like to know how I would handle pagination though. Naturally this involves passing in a page parameter etc and I'm not sure how to do this without subsclassing the Scope class.

Answer (score 4):

The `policy_scope(Record)` method returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, then you can chain the pagination method, depending on which gem you use (`will_paginate`, `kaminari`).

```
def index
  @records = policy_scope(Record).paginate(params[:page])
end
```

Comment: I had issues in this where I was filtering my @records equivalent using an ActiveRecord 'find' instead of 'where' so was only returning one record that was not an ActiveRecord relation type. The solution above worked fine once I solved the bug in my pundit scopes on the index.

Answer (score 1):

For googlers. The answer above is technically correct, but with most recent versions of Kaminari (mine is 0.17), the method to chain is `page(params[:page])`